# I want to use the Microsoft Office API in JavaScript as I am developing a Chrome extension, and am facing an issue using the script of the Office

Tags: javascript, office365, office-addins, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

> Refused to load the script 'https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

This is the error I am getting while I load my Chrome extension, and doesn't allow me to use the Office APIs.

This is a part of my manifest.json file version 3.

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'wasm-eval' https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js;"
}
```

**Solution which worked for me and removed csp errors:**

After Using Sandbox:
sandbox.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Sandbox Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="sandbox-content">
    <p>This is a sandboxed page content.</p>
  </div>
  <script src="sandbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sandbox.js

```
console.log("you are in sandbox.js");
Office.onReady(function (info) {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    // Do Excel-specific initialization (for example, make add-in task pane's
    // appearance compatible with Excel "green").
  }
  if (info.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC) {
    // Make minor layout changes in the task pane.
  }
  console.log(`Office.js is now ready in ${info.host} on ${info.platform}`);
});
```

In my main script I am trying to connect with the sandbox.html, so that I can use the office API.
So in the mainscript.js which is connected to the chrome-extension tab, i called

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("sandbox.html");
  iframe.id = "sandbox";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

This created an iframe on the page and i could get use the sandbox.js.

Manifest.json

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com"
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
  },
```

Comment: ManifestV3 forbids external JS in normal extension pages. You can use it inside a [sandbox page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/sandbox).

Comment: i added sandbox page and added the ms office script in the sandboxed page, but to access it I found solutions which use iframe which is created in the content script and then do iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("sandbox.html");

This lets me access the sandbox.html and sandbox.js but I still get the same error, am I doing something wrong in this

Comment: It's unclear why you need a content script and an iframe, please add the code and more info to the question.

Comment: i have made an edit and added code and explained what I want exactly and the errors I am facing. Thankyou

Comment: Replace `extension_pages` with `sandbox`.

Comment: thankyou that worked, i dont have errors related to csp now.